# How to get user info from Okta, other than name, surname and email?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, crud, okta

I would like to get other info from Okta, because with `this.props.auth.getUser()` I’ll receive only email, name and surname about user. But there are many data on Okta for example state, city, street address, zip code and so on.

I’m creating a web app with ReactJS and Node express and the login is managed by Okta (https://developer.okta.com/), then I would like to store the Okta information about users in a database.

```
async checkAuthentication() {
  const authenticated = await this.props.auth.isAuthenticated();

  if (authenticated !== this.state.authenticated) {
    const user = await this.props.auth.getUser();

    console.log(this.props.auth);
    this.setState({
      authenticated,
      user
    });
    this.getUsers();
  }
}

async getUsers() {
  let params = "";
  let url = "";

  if (this.state.user != null) {
    params += "EMAIL=" + this.state.user.email;
  }

  url = params == null ? "/user" : "/user?";
  url += params;
  this.state.users = await this.fetch('get', url);

  if (this.state.users && Object.keys(this.state.users).length == 0) {
    this.saveUser();
  }
}

async saveUser() {
  var user = {
    EMAIL: this.state.user.email,
    NAME: this.state.user.given_name,
    SURNAME: this.state.user.family_name,
    //ORGANIZATION: "this.state.user.organization",
    //PHONE = "this.state.user.primaryPhone",
    //STATE = "this.state.user.state",
    //STREET_ADDRESS = "this.state.user.streetAddress",
    //ZIP_CODE = "this.state.user.zipCode",
  };

  await this.fetch('post', '/user', user);
}
```

Here I would like to save the other data from Okta.

```
//ORGANIZATION: "this.state.user.organization",
//PHONE = "this.state.user.primaryPhone",
//STATE = "this.state.user.state",
//STREET_ADDRESS = "this.state.user.streetAddress",
//ZIP_CODE = "this.state.user.zipCode",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auth.getUser() returns the details available under /userinfo endpoint on the authorization server through which the user got authenticated and authorized, as described here.

If you would like to publish other details also on this /endpoint, please do the following:

- navigate from your Okta tenant to Admin >> API >> Authorization Server >> your authorization server
- under Claims tab, add new claims with the user's profile values and, under "Include in token type", select "ID Token" and "Userinfo / id_token request"

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what you want as scope. Okta has default scopes which are the following offline_access, phone, address, email, profile, openid.In the configuration, you can use these docs https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/

Comment: Using the function getUser() from okta I'm having only this informations:

`email: "fabioxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"
email_verified: true
family_name: "xxxxxx"
given_name: "Fabio"
locale: "IT"
name: "Fabio xxxxx"
preferred_username: "fabioxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
sub: "xxxxxxxxx"
updated_at: 1547719125
zoneinfo: ""`